# Is it safe to split long JavaScript if conditions into multiple lines?

Tags: javascript

```
if ( true && true ||
  false && false ||
  true && true ) {
  console.log( 'Splitting condition into multiple lines worked!' );
}
```

Does the above snippet of code work in all relevant browsers?

PS: I'm also concerned about IE8 as it has too big a marketshare to ignore as of today.

Comment: It should, we actually have a 150 character/line limit in our coding standards so sometimes have to break it out like this.

Comment: [Sort of related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: whitespace is ignored inside of `if` statement conditions (no auto semis)

Answer (score 29):

Browsers are very forgiving when it comes to whitespace and line breaks in conditionals. You can honestly get away with a lot of things (for better or worse haha). Right now these two formats are the industry standard. Personally, I like the syntax in the second syntax more.

**Syntax A**

```
if (
  a === 123 &&
  b === 'abc'
) { ... }
```

**Syntax B**

```
if (
  a === 123
  && b === 'abc'
) { ... }
```

AirBnb's preferred syntax: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1380

Answer (score 22):

This is explained in the spec:

> [**7.3 Line Terminators**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3)
>
> Like white space characters, line terminator characters are used to
>   improve source text readability and to separate tokens (indivisible
>   lexical units) from each other. However, unlike white space
>   characters, line terminators have some influence over the behaviour of
>   the syntactic grammar. In general, line terminators may occur between
>   any two tokens, but there are a few places where they are forbidden by
>   the syntactic grammar. Line terminators also affect the process of
>   [automatic semicolon insertion (7.9)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9).
>
> [**7.9 Automatic Semicolon Insertion**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)
>
> Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, variable statement,
>   expression statement, `do-while` statement, `continue` statement,
>   `break` statement, `return` statement, and `throw` statement) must be
>   terminated with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear
>   explicitly in the source text. For convenience, however, such
>   semicolons may be omitted from the source text in certain situations.
>   These situations are described by saying that semicolons are
>   automatically inserted into the source code token stream in those
>   situations.

So in most cases you can do it. And your case is one of these.

Answer (score 3):

I also recently found myself having a very long condition. 
Below you will find an example of how I solved it, using *Boolean()*:

```
const a = new Array('', '  ', '    ');
const empty = Boolean(a[0].trim() == '' || 
                      a[1].trim() == '' || 
                      a[2].trim() == '' ||);
if (!empty){
   console.log("Fine!");
}else{
   console.log("Not fine!");   
}
```

I hope I can help you.