# Ambiguity in the following without line continuation?

Tags: javascript

Is the following function ambiguous in javascript?

```
equals(o) {
    return (this.x == o.x) 
        && (this.y == o.y);
}
```

That is, because it's spread across two lines, do I need to move the `&&` to the line above? What are the rules for when I need to be concerned about spreading a statement across multiple lines?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154339/is-it-safe-to-split-long-javascript-if-conditions-into-multiple-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154339/is-it-safe-to-split-long-javascript-if-conditions-into-multiple-lines)? Your syntax is fine and readable.

Comment: This looks like a question which will mainly get opinion based answers.  Is there a specific coding style you are trying to follow?

Comment: `&&` is a binary operator. It’s impossible for the two lines to be two separate statements, no matter which line you put the `&&` on. Have you seen [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](/q/2846283/4642212)?

Comment: @Trisped nope I just want to make sure I don't get errors in terms of putting it over multiple lines. Style I'm not concerned about.

Comment: @SebastianSimon no `&&` is logical: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND. `&` is bitwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND

Comment: @David542 I mean the other meaning of binary: requiring two operands. As opposed to unary or ternary or any other _n_-ary for _n_ ≠ 2, or even variadic.